# Error around detectAndComputer method in openCV python code

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I'm using python 3.6.3, opencv-contrib-python-3.3.1.11 in VS Code.  I'm trying to run the following code:

```
import cv2
image1 = cv2.imread('PATH.image1.jpg',0)
image2 = cv2.imread('PATH.image2.jpg',0)

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndComputer(image1,None)
kp2, desc2 = sift.detectAndComputer(image2,None)
```

I've read about the change in SIFT for earlier versions of openCV and the later versions making a user install the opencv contrib instead.  My error isn't around the create but rather around the detectAndComputer method.  This is the error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'cv2.xfeatures2d_SIFT' object has no attribute 'detectAndComputer'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct call is `kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(image1,None)` rather than `detectAndComputer`.

There are some details on this process and code syntax [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html)

Comment: Thanks!  bad eyesight.

Answer (score 0):

Should be sift.detectAndCompute not sift.detectAndCompute(r)